# My IF statement is not working

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C programming and I have started doing my first assignment. in this assignment i am supposed to print out some information to the users and ask for their output and based on their output i should do some calculations and print out the results. I'm not quite sure where, but my results are either zero or a number unrelated to the user's input.
Can someone please help me out ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c=0, f=0, q=0, w=0;
    int memory = 0, monitor = 0, hard = 0, subtotal = 0, hst = 0, total = 0, a = 0;
    printf("Welcome to the IPC company's computer System calculator\n");
    printf("Enter the package desired \n");


    printf("(1:basic, 2:professional, 3:game system)\n");
    scanf("%d", &c);


    switch (c){

        // if the user chooses the basic option
    case 1:

        printf("Enter additional memory required\n");
        printf("(0: 4 GB included, 1: 8 GB, 2: 12 GB)\n");
        q = scanf("%d", &q);
        // The additional amount that needs to be added to the package, based on user's choice


        switch (q){
        case 1:
            memory = 99;
        case 2:
            memory = 189;
        case 0:
            memory = 0;
        }

        printf("Enter monitor required\n");
        printf("(0: 21 inch LED included, 1: 27 inch LED )\n");
        w = scanf("%d", &w);

        switch (w){
        case 0:
            monitor = 0;
        case 1:
            monitor = 199;
        }
        printf("Enter Hard Drive required\n");
        printf("(0: 512 GB included, 1: 128 GB SSD )\n");
        f = scanf("%d", &f);

        switch (f){
        case 0:
            hard = 0;
        case 1:
            hard = 119;
        }
        subtotal = memory + monitor + hard + 599;
        hst = subtotal*(13 / 100);
        total = hst + subtotal;


        // invoices 

        printf("basic package: 599.00\n");

        // price of memory based on user's choice
        if (q = 1){
            printf("8 GB Memory: 99.00\n");
        }
        else if (q = 2){
            printf(" 12 GB Memory: 189.00\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("4 GB Memory: 0.00\n");
        }

        // price of monitor base on user's choice

        if (w = 1){
            printf("27 inch LED Monitor : 199.00\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("21 inch LED Monitor: 0.00\n");
        }

        // price of hard drive based on user's choice
        if (f = 1){
            printf("128 GB Hard Drive: 119.00\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("512 GB Hard Drive: 0.00\n");
        }

        printf("sub total: %.02f\n ", subtotal);
        printf("HST: %.02f\n", hst);
        printf("Total: %.02f\n", total);

        break;
```

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: could you please post the code you made so far?

Comment: Might be useful: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I apologize for the unorganized post. i tried to delete it and post it again but i couldn't figure out how.

Comment: You're new here. The first rule is...don't panic. ...And always bring a towel. Beyond that, you can edit your post to include your code. Just paste it in.

Comment: very likely you are using the assignment operator for comparision, `=` is for assignment, for comparison you need `==`.

Comment: This is one part of the program . I apologize again for any inconvenience .

Comment: Your first `scanf` shows that you know how to properly use `scanf`. However, your further `scanf`s make no sense at all. What is that `q = scanf("%d", &q)` supposed to mean? `w = scanf("%d", &w)`? Why are you trying to assign the return value of `scanf` to the variable you just read?

Comment: I am trying to save user's input which is 0,1 or 2 so that i can use it for the if statement at the end of the program .

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to ask for user's choice and then save the input which is 0,1 or 2 . And then print out the price of user's choice . but i either get zero or another option's price.

Comment: @iharob You deserve a medal.

Comment: @zenith I posted the comment before the OP posted the code, did you notice that? And you too deserve one, nice answer.

Comment: @iharob Yeah I noticed that. And thanks haha.

Comment: @Ella: Firstly, where did you get the idea that in order to "save user's input" you have to save the return value of `scanf`??? Secondly, look at your first `scanf`. How come your first `scanf` works perfectly fine, even though you are not "trying to save user's input" there?

Answer (score 2):

#### Usage of `scanf`

Your first `scanf("%d", &c)` is correct.

But later when you do this: `q = scanf("%d", &q)` the assignment to `q` doesn't do what you think it does.

Just use `scanf("%d", &some_variable)` everywhere where you have `some_variable =` before `scanf`, that's the correct way to use `scanf`.

---

#### Integer division

The division `13 / 100` will always result to `0`. The reason for that is, because both `13` and `100` are integers, integer division is performed and thus the result of that is also an integer. 13/100 would be 0.13 but is rounded down to 0 to representable as an integer.

The solution would be to make the numbers floating point number, like this:

```
13.0 / 100.0
```

Now floating point division is performed and the result is `0.13`, exactly as wanted.

---

#### Comparison with `==`

You're using `=` for comparison, when you should use `==`. For example:

```
if (q = 1)
```

The above line assigns `1` to `q`. It does *not* compare `q` to `1`. To compare, write:

```
if (q == 1)
```

And replace that everywhere where you tried to compare with `=`.

---

#### `printf` format specifiers

```
printf("sub total: %.02f\n ", subtotal);
```

You have specified the `printf` format specifier `f` which is used to output `double` values. I.e. you're trying to print out `subtotal` as a `double` value, but `subtotal` is declared as an `int`. That's why it only outputs `0.0`.

To fix the problem, either replace `f` with `d` to output an integer value (then you won't need the `.02` to specify decimal places either):

```
printf("sub total: %d\n ", subtotal);
```

Or, declare `subtotal` as a `double` if you want it to be a floating point number, aka able to represent digits after the decimal point:

```
double subtotal = 0.0;
```

Do this for all values you were trying to output with `%.02f`.

---

#### Conclusion

I would recommend you to write code in pieces, little by little. Only add something new when you're sure that your old code is working 100% correctly. That way, this many errors will not arise at once.

Comment: So I should delete the variable before the scanf s and simply use the addressed variable in the if statement ?

Comment: @Ella Yes, `scanf` writes the value to the variable you pass it as an argument.

Comment: Now i get zero for everything .

Comment: @Ella I just noticed you're also using `=` instead of `==` for comparison. Check my updated answer. Does it now work?

Comment: No I am still getting 0.00 after all of this. I think my if statement for printing the results is not working properly. I need it to print out a different result based on the Value of q . but it gives me zero no matter what I do.

Comment: @Ella Okay so I noticed that you're misusing the `printf` format specifiers as well, check my edit for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I found in your code is

```
q=(scanf.........
```

use this and it will work

```
scanf("%d",&q)
```

You also need to fix your `switch` statements:

```
    switch (q){
    case 1:
        memory = 99;
        break;  // Without a break the program will continue and aexcute the code in the next case too!
    case 2:
        memory = 189;
        break;
    case 0:
        memory = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I just did what u told me, and now i get zero for everything when i run it.

Comment: I added how to fix the problem with your `switch` statements. You need to add `break;` in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`if (q = 1)` <- this is always true, can't be false, because it is assigning the value of `1` to `q` then evaluating that statement, which is always `1` and always boolean true.

`if (q==1)` <- this is for comparison, or better yet, put the constant first
`if(1==q)` <- if you mix up the 1, or 2 equals signs there will be a compiler error.

also you should have a warning, read all of your warnings and resolve those issues.

Comment: Always true? What if `if (q = 0)` - the assignment operator returns a reference to the object, so if the value is 0 it will be false. Assignment of 1 will always be true, but certainly not any assignment  (well, any except 0)

Comment: I corrected that but I am still getting zero for everything. It is like my variables are not recording the results and my if statements are somehow not working.

Comment: @ddriver, `if(q=0)` isn't the same as `if (q=1)` if the compiler is changing constants on you, then it is time to get a new compiler

Comment: @Ella did you correct the 4 places that you used the same pattern, and if it is still an issue post your 'corrected' code.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assignment operator

`==` is equality operator

If you flip the operands you will get an error, since you cannot `1 = w` (assign to a literal), but you can `1 == w` (check for equality)

The asignment operator returns a reference to the same object, so what you essentially do is:

```
q = 1;
if (q)
```

Which will always be true, since 1 is "true".

Comment: Now i get 0.00 for everything.

Comment: @Ella - there are many other things wrong with your code besides the if statements. Walk through your code with all the information learned in the answers and you will eventually fix it.

Comment: I fixed most of my errors . Now it is half working. But when it comes to calculating the subtotal I dont get the right answer. Can you please tell me how i can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

> q = scanf("%d", &q);

This won't work because 'scanf' function returns the number of items that it read as an input.
Instead, use : `scanf("%d",&q)`